# why combBox.selectedItem can't be null?

Tags: entity-framework, combobox

I have a button named button2 which should remove items from a table in a database through Entity Framework.

I have a `ComboBox` that selects an item which should be deleted. But when I don't select any item this exception happens for `SelectedItem.ToString`

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` every time I run the program the `else` branch will be executed even if I choose an item

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstEntities db = new firstEntities();

    var st = db.Students.ToList<Student>()
               .Find(a => a.Family == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

    if (st != null)
    {
        db.Students.Remove(st);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("you didnt select any student");
}
```

Comment: Improved spelling and formatting. Also, you should show how you bind the entities to the combobox (value member etc.). And, you present a problem but you don't ask a question. That's an important difference. Further, a null reference exception shouldn't be too hard to spot by debugging your code.

Comment: thanks a lot for your note. My question was why selectedItem can't be null and what should I do? I bind a column of a a table to the combobox. I solve my problem by moving line 3 and 5 into the if statement. and I changed the if condition to : if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)